# Should we use “de” after “en dessous”?

Tags: usage, indications-de-lieu, prépositions

I know that "sous" is not to be followed by "de": for instance "sous l'escalier" is correct, and "sous de l'escalier" is not.

But what about "en dessous"? Which usage is correct:

- en dessous l'escalier
- en dessous de l'escalier

Also, is it acceptable to use "dessous" alone e.g. "le chien est dessous la table ?" Or "Sort de dessous le lit !"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second one:

> En dessous de l'escalier.

Note that you can also use *en dessous* on its own, while *sous* should always be followed by something. For instance:

> Le livre est-il sur la table ? Non, en dessous. Le livre est sous la table.

As for the sentences you propose with just *dessous* (not *en dessous*), they are both correct (although *le chien est sous la table* sound more natural to me).